# Eastern beaver h4 relay kit motorcycle, capacitor before the high beam to power relay switch

Tags: motorcycle, headlight, relay, battery-cable, capacitor

Everything works fine except the relay doesn't get any power to the high beam switch if the revs are above tickover.  I'm thinking of adding a capacitor some where to just get a bit of power to the relay so that once it switches the power will now flow.  Without power to the relay the light doesnt felt the power.  The power is just blocked from the relay until it switches.   Once switched it's fine the light works and no powers needed from the relay.
What size capacitor would I need to just get some juice to the relay so it switches the power source?  It's a 12v battery, charges around 14.39v ...  I thought I needed a 16v 0.3uf capacitor.   Is this correct?   12v lights and the power draw to the light is 3.75 amps. It's only going to the relay so not sure if I need that much.

It does this  because the power supply goes through a high beam switch and because the power now comes from the battery this is preventing the switch powering the relay

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Are they just flickering or completely shut off? 16v is much too low. You need 25V at least and even this is cutting it close. 50V or more is best. UF probably doesn't matter that much in this case. I bet anything 5-15uf would be fine if its just flickering, going a little dim. If they are cutting off completely then you have issues that need to be address beyond trying to add a capacitor.

Comment: At idle they are fine, small accelerating,  they flicker,  more accelerating and they go out.

Comment: It's just on the high beam .  If I try to switch between hi and low beam under acceleration the relay wont switch the light until the revs drop.  This is why I thought adding a capacitor would allow that power draw to switch it and turn it on. On low beam it's fine,  the light works normal under acceleration.  But it is also on high beam they just flicker and go out completely.  So I thought a  capacitor would prevent them going out and keep the power going to them.   What would be the issue?  It's like the motorcycle draws too much power even though the voltage on the  battery stays at 14.80v

Comment: What kind of uf what I need if they are going completely out?

Comment: All I have done is wire relay kit to the front headlight

Comment: The ground for the relay is attached to the battery would it be better hooked to the frame?

Comment: The lights no longer flicker but the relay just doesnt switch if the bike is revving at all. It just switches when it's on tickover.

Comment: If its not switching then its a bad connection, failing relay, low, voltage or its not getting the proper command from control module. You'd have to diagnose which one is causing it no switching.

Comment: it just switches over with a little bit of power just enough to power the relay.  Then the light will use the power from the battery through the relay wire .  What would be a suitable capictor, would you still recommend the same?  If it's a 50v capacitor it will only charge to about 14v right?  And the uf just needs to power the relay so it switches